# How to create rack application to be used by Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

Rails itself is based around multiple independent processes that are stateless inbetween requests. I need to add a stateful centralized service (a game automatcher) to my Rails app.

From what little I know I should make that stateful service a rack application. Is there some tutorial out there on how to make a rack application and also importantly how to communicate with it from Rails. What is the idiomatic way to deploy it with Rails and the idiomatic place to put it in my git Rails codebase?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could clarify what you are trying to accomplish. Rack is strictly speaking merely an interface that defines a contract for a ruby application to process an HTTP request.

If you could provide more details on what your "game automatcher" should do, I could provide a more useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my question answered in another question:

[How to read POST data in rack request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458334/how-to-read-post-data-in-rack-request)

```
require 'json'

class Greeter
  def call(env)
    req = Rack::Request.new(env)
    if req.post?
      puts req.POST()
    end
    [200, {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}, [{x:"Hello World!"}.to_json]]
  end
end

run Greeter.new
```

and use `JSON.parse( req.body.read )` to parse POST data.

Answer (score 0):

Another option other than rack is to [daemonize](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/) your app.

Comment: As far as I know middleware Rails is part of the Rails request handling. But it isn't a separate process running outside of Rails which is what I want.

Comment: daemonizing it is still a valid option, though. You will have a separate process serving data on a socket or on the localhost, just like memcached for instance

Comment: If you want to do stuff independently of any http requests coming in, you will need an additional proces. Why do you want to avoid that? Alternatively, you can start threads inside your rails processes, but that can be a recipe for headache in production. A rails process shouldn't be concerned with doing anything else than responding to http requests.