# How to read POST data in rack request

Tags: ruby, rack

When I run the curl command

```
curl -v -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"abc", "id":"12", "subject":"my subject"}' http://localhost:9292
```

to send a POST request with data to my Rack application, my code prints out `{}`. That is coming from `puts req.POST()` in the code below.

Why does it print out `{}` instead of the POST data? And how do I correctly access the POST data in my Rack application?

```
require 'json'

class Greeter
  def call(env)
    req = Rack::Request.new(env)
    if req.post?
      puts req.POST()
    end
    [200, {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}, [{x:"Hello World!"}.to_json]]
  end
end

run Greeter.new
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From reading the docs for POST, looks like it is giving you parsed data based on other content types. If you want to process "application/json", you probably need to

```
JSON.parse( req.body.read )
```

instead. To check this, try

```
puts req.body.read
```

where you currently have `puts req.POST`.

---

`req.body` is an I/O object, not a string. See the [`body`](http://rdoc.info/gems/rack/1.2.1/Rack/Request#body-instance_method) documentation and view the source. You can see that this is in fact the same as mudasobwa's answer.

Note that other code in a Rack application may expect to read the same I/O, such as the param parsers in Sinatra or Rails. To ensure that they see the same data and not get an error, you may want to call `req.body.rewind`, possibly both before and after reading the request body in your code. However, if you are in such a situation, you might instead consider whether your framework has options to process JSON directly via some option on the controller or request content-type handler declaration etc - most likely there will be an option to handle this kind of request within the framework.

Comment: FYI - Reading the I/O stream from middleware can break a Rails app. When you've got the value, you need to make sure to run `req.env['rack.input'].rewind` to reset the stream.

Comment: @lookitsatravis: Thanks, I've added a note about that to the answer. The OP is using Rack directly without Rails or other framework, so it will not apply in their case. If you are using Rails, there will be other ways to read `application/json` requests

Comment: @Niel: Agreed! In my particular use case, I am using [rack-attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) and one of my login throttle checks requires that I parse the request body before Rails reads it. Edge case, to be sure, but it led me to this post and to my comment. Cheers!

Comment: @lookitsatravis the same exact use-case brought me here. I am sure you've long since dealt with your problem, but for anyone reading: the easiest way to not pull your hair out when trying to filter by post body data in rack-attack is to just import ActiveSupport into the file. Reading and rewinding the I/O stream is a very annoying process.

Comment: Correction, I meant ActionDispatch above

Answer (score 17):

Try:

```
env['rack.input'].read
```

I found it in "[How to receive a JSON object with Rack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707034/cant-receive-json-object-with-rack-ruby-server)" and, though it still sounds weird to me, it likely works.

Comment: Not only will it read only the first lin, it will aadd a seperator (by default `\n`) to the stream. This will break things like JSON parsing and request signing. Much better to do `env[''rack.input'].read`

Comment: In case anyone else is confused by @ianks's comment, I think that was referring to an earlier version of this answer which used `gets` instead of `read`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
req.params
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: To my knowledge, params are not readable in Rack for posts. Rails is what normalizes post body into the params object as far as I know

Comment: This is the working solution for Rails 7, the other ones didn't work for POST requests.